# Mongo single node replicaset on Docker, MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, replicaset

I'm trying to set up a single node MongoDB replicaset on Docker and connect to it within my node app, but the connection is refused. The connection works fine if I use mongo as a standalone instance and no replicaset.

This is how I connect to mongo on my node app :

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://admin:secretpass@app_mongodb:27017/dbname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0")
```

And this is the error I receive :

```
/var/www/worker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824
const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Mongo logs show that the app tries to connect :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-27T10:22:46.410+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.10:41318","uuid":"2e1ccbc5-3162-4f64-80f3-8be580079ef6","connectionId":68,"connectionCount":11}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-27T10:22:46.417+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn68","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.10:41318","client":"conn68","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"4.11.0"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.0-12-amd64"},"platform":"Node.js v19.5.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.11.0|6.7.5"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-27T10:22:46.425+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn68","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.10:41318","uuid":"2e1ccbc5-3162-4f64-80f3-8be580079ef6","connectionId":68,"connectionCount":10}}
```

docker-compose.yml :

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    mongodb:
        container_name: app_mongodb
        build:
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
            x-bake:
                no-cache: true
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secretpass
        volumes:
            - ./db:/data/db
        networks:
            - proxy
        restart: unless-stopped
    worker:
        container_name: app_worker
        image: "node:latest"
        command: "npm run dev"
        user: "node"
        working_dir: /var/www/worker
        environment:
            WAIT_HOSTS: app_mongodb:27017
        volumes:
            - ./worker:/var/www/worker
        networks:
            - proxy
        links:
            - mongodb
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
        restart: unless-stopped
networks:
    proxy:
        external: true
```

Dockerfile :

```bash
FROM mongo

# Initiate replica set
RUN echo "secretpasswordkey" > "/tmp/replica.key"
RUN chmod 600 /tmp/replica.key
RUN chown 999:999 /tmp/replica.key

CMD ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--keyFile", "/tmp/replica.key"]
```

And I also run this command with mongosh after starting up the container (is there a way to add that to the Dockerfile instead by the way?) :

```bash
rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', members: [{_id:1, 'host':'127.0.0.1:27017'}]})
```

A quick check shows the replicaset is indeed initialized :

```json
rs0 [direct: primary] admin> rs.status()
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:44.062Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("1"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 1,
  writeMajorityCount: 1,
  votingMembersCount: 1,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 1,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:39.161Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:39.161Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:39.161Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1674815679, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:25:49.015Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("1"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815148, i: 1 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815148, i: 1 }), t: Long("-1") },
    numVotesNeeded: 1,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:25:49.082Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:25:49.111Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: '127.0.0.1:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 643,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:39.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:39.161Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:35:39.161Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1674815149, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2023-01-27T10:25:49.000Z"),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("a211cfe3faa237bf8a30ccbc8ca929eea704f467", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7193276291800367109")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1674815739, i: 1 })
}
```

Ideas on what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure? Connection string `mongodb://admin:secretpass@app_mongodb:27017`  does not match to error message `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` Try to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: What is the reason to create a **single member** MongoDB replicaset?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your comment ! It helped a lot. I did not realize at first that the connection url in the `initiate()` instruction was going to be used during client connection.

Also to answer your question, I need to use Change Streams in my app and that feature is not available in standalone mode. Since I have only one server at my disposal and performance is more important than availability in my case, I figured only one instance is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @WernfriedDomscheit's comment pointing me to the right direction, I realized I have to give the mongodb container hostname instead of 127.0.0.1 when initiating the replicaset :

```json
rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', members: [{_id: 1, 'host': 'mongodb:27017'}]})
```

I was able to automate initialization by adding a healthcheck routine to my docker-compose.yml file. The Dockerfile is not necessary anymore.

The whole mongodb container description is now this :

```yaml
    mongodb:
        container_name: app_mongodb
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGODB_USER}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGODB_PASS}
        volumes:
            - ./db:/data/db
        networks:
            - proxy
        restart: unless-stopped
        healthcheck:
            test: test $$(echo 'rs.initiate({_id':' "rs0", members':' [{_id':' 1, "host"':' "mongodb':'27017"}]}) || rs.status().ok' | mongosh -u $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --quiet) -eq 1
            interval: 10s
            start_period: 30s
```

It's important to set the host in the `initiate()` and not leave the arguments empty because otherwise by default it'll setup the replicaset using the container ID as host, and if the container is removed and restarted the replicaset won't work anymore as the new container ID will be different.

Comment: Initiate may take a few seconds. Better add `while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) { sleep(1000) }` after `rs.initiate()`

Comment: Your explanation helped point me to a solution for my problem which is documented in the included link. However I ended up solving it by including the "hostname" parameter for the container. E.g. hostname: app_mongodb. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747148/upgrading-a-sharded-mongodb-cluster-in-docker-container-id-being-used-to-connec

Answer (score 0):

In my case that it was hosted at a VPS, I had to change "mongodb" to the Remote IP address of the VPS:

rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', members: [{_id: 1, 'host': 'MY_VPS_IP:27017'}]})